# How to tokenize this?

Tags: lexical-analysis

I am trying to hand code a tokenizer. I keep on reading the characters which can be part of a token. For example an integer can only contain digits. So in the below text I keep on reading the characters until I find a non-digit character. So I get 123 as the token. Next I get ( as the token, and then abc as identifier. This is fine as ( is a delimiter.

```
123(abc
```

However, in the below text I get 123 as integer and then abc as identifier. But actually this in not valid since there is no delimiter between them.

```
123abc(
```

Should the tokenizer check for delimiters and report an error? If yes what tokens should be returned and where should the tokenizer continue reading from after an invalid token is found?

Or should the tokenizer simply return 123 as integer and abc as identifier and let the parser detect the errors?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the tokenizer (or [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis)) performs no checking of valid syntax.

The role of a lexer is to split the input into tokens, which can then be transformed into a syntax tree by the [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser). Therefore, it'd usually be the job of the parser to perform such a check.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider generating your tokenizer or lexer. Tools like [Flex](https://github.com/westes/flex/) or [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) should help. And you might also generate your parser with ANTLR or [Bison](http://www.gnu.org/s/bison/)

If you insist on hand-coding your lexer (and your parser), having some look-ahead is extremely helpful in practice. For instance, you could read your input line by line and tokenize inside the current line (with the ability to inspect the next few characters).

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a gray area, but most hand-coded lexers just do the tokenizing, and let the parser decide whether the stream of tokens make sense.

Comment: In such case you might give a lexical error, since `123abc` is not a token.

Answer (score 0):

If "123abc" is an invalid token then you should handle it as soon as you spot it since it's directly related to the way tokens are defined, *not* how they interact with each other (which would be the lexer's job). It's an orthographic error rather than a grammar-related one.

There are multiple ways to go about it:

- You could abort the parsing and just throw some exception, leaving the caller with no tokens or just the tokens you had successfully parsed until then. This will save you any "recovery" logic and might be enough for your use case. Although, if you're parsing stuff for syntax highlighting for instance, this would probably not be sufficient as you don't want all of the remaining code to look unparsed.

  Example: A conforming XML parser could use this for fatal errors if there's no need to handle malformed markup, just spit out a basic error and quit.
- Alternatively, you could insert an "error" token with proper metadata about the nature of the error and skip ahead to the next valid token.

  You might need to have heuristics in your lexer to handle the error token gracefully and find how to interpret further tokens when an error token is found inside an nested expression (like, should you consider the expression has ended? look for a closing token? etc.).

  Anyway, this approach will allow for error tokens to be used to display precise info about the location and nature of errors encountered (think inline error reporting in a GUI).